# Find the number of function $f: \{ 1,2,...,n \} \rightarrow \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ which satisfy $|f(k+1)-f(k)| \geq 3$ for $k=1,2,...,n-1.$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n \geq 2$ be a positive integer. Find the number of function $f: \{ 1,2,...,n \} \rightarrow \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ which satisfy $|f(k+1)-f(k)| \geq 3$ for $k=1,2,...,n-1.$ There is a sipmle way? I think it will something about sequence fibonacci.

Answer (score 1):

A function from $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $[5]=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is simply a sequence of $n$ integers from the set $[5]$. The restriction that $|f(k+1)-f(k)|\ge 3$ means that

- $1$ may be followed by $4$ or $5$;
- $2$ must be followed by $5$;
- $3$ cannot be followed or preceded by anything, so since $n\ge 2$, $3$ cannot appear in the sequence;
- $4$ must be followed by $1$; and
- $5$ may be followed by $1$ or $2$.

Next, note that if $f$ is such a function, so is the function

$$\hat f:[n]\to[5]:k\mapsto 6-f(k)$$

that replaces each $1$ in the $f$-sequence with $5$ and vice versa, and each $2$ with $4$ and vice versa. Thus, there is a bijection between the valid functions $f$ for which $f(1)=1$ and those for which $f(1)=5$, and between those for which $f(1)=2$ and those for which $f(2)=4$.

Let $a_n$ be the number of valid functions for which $f(1)=1$, $b_n$ the number for which $f(1)=2$, and $c_n$ the total number of valid functions from $[n]$ to $[5]$. Use the foregoing observations to show that

- $c_n=2a_n+2b_n$;
- $a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$; and
- $b_n=a_{n-1}$.

Now put the pieces together: $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, so

$$\begin{align*}
c_n&=2(a_n+b_n)\\
&=2(a_n+a_{n-1})\\
&=2a_{n+1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, we can answer the question completely if we can find a closed form for the numbers $a_n$. Notice that they satisfy the same recurrence as the Fibonacci numbers, and use that observation and what you know about the Fibonacci numbers to get a closed form for $a_n$ and hence for $c_n$.

Answer (score 0):

(to be simplified)

- Let $a_n$ be the number of functions where $f(n)=1$.
- Let $b_n$ be the number of functions where $f(n)=2$.
- Let $c_n$ be the number of functions where $f(n)=4$.
- Let $d_n$ be the number of functions where $f(n)=5$.

Then:

- $a_{n+1} = c_n + d_n$
- $b_{n+1} = d_n$
- $c_{n+1} = a_n$
- $d_{n+1} = a_n + b_n$

We then attempt to convert each sequence to be recursive only to itself. That means, we would like it to be $a_{n+1} = \text{only a and n}$.

- $a_n = c_{n-1} + d_{n-1} = 2a_{n-2} + b_{n-2}$
- $b_n = d_{n-1} = a_{n-2} + b_{n-2} = a_n - a_{n-2}$
- 1: $a_n = 2a_{n-2} + b_{n-2} = 3a_{n-2} - a_{n-4}$
- $a_n = 2a_{n-2} + b_{n-2} = 2b_n - b_{n-2}$
- 2: $b_n = a_{n-2} + b_{n-2} = 3b_{n-2} - b_{n-4}$

Similarly:

- 3: $c_n = 3c_{n-2} - c_{n-4}$
- 4: $d_n = 3d_{n-2} - d_{n-4}$

And, by symmetry, $a$ and $d$ have the same seed. $b$ and $c$ also have the same seed. Also, we know that $b$ and $c$ are just $a$ and $d$ shifted by $1$.

By treating odd and even numbers of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ as different sequences, we obtain this general formula:

$$C_1(0.5(3-\sqrt5))^n+C_2(0.5(3+\sqrt5))^n$$

The seeds:

- $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, $a_4=5$, $a_5=8$
- $b_2=1$, $b_3=2$, $b_4=3$, $b_5=5$
- $c_2=1$, $c_3=2$, $c_4=3$, $c_5=5$
- $d_2=2$, $c_3=3$, $d_4=5$, $d_5=8$

The formulae:

$$a_{\text{even}} = b_{\text{odd}} = (1-0.4\sqrt5)(0.5(3-\sqrt5))^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}+(1+0.4\sqrt5)(0.5(3+\sqrt5))^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}$$

$$a_{\text{odd}} = b_{\text{even}} = (0.5-0.3\sqrt5)(0.5(3-\sqrt5))^{\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil}+(0.5+0.3\sqrt5)(0.5(3+\sqrt5))^{\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil}$$

Therefore:

$$f_n=2[(1-0.4\sqrt5)(0.5(3-\sqrt5))^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}+(1+0.4\sqrt5)(0.5(3+\sqrt5))^{\left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor}+(0.5-0.3\sqrt5)(0.5(3-\sqrt5))^{\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil}+(0.5+0.3\sqrt5)(0.5(3+\sqrt5))^{\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil}]$$

(to be simplified)

Comment: By symmetry, you have $a_n=d_n, \; b_n=c_n$. Use that and you have a two variable system, which you can combine to get a second order linear recurrence.

Comment: ie $a_{n+1}=c_n+d_n=a_{n-1}+a_n$, 
Which is Fibonnaci.